# Wrapping the cancel_comment_reply_link()

Tags: comment-form

This question is related to [another question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrap-cancel-comment-reply-link-in-div?replies=2), unfortunately the answer provided does not work.

I used to have a template to replace the `comment_form()` but since this practice is viewed in Themecheck plugin as an error, I need to be able to customize/filter almost everything in the `comment_form()`.

So how can I filter the `cancel_comment_reply_link()` to have this form?

```
<p class="cancel-comment-reply pull-left"><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></p>
```

I followed the provided resource in the below answer and now I'm getting 3 links for `cancel_comment_reply_link()`, perhaps there is a way to have only one? Sample code:

```
$cancel_text = __("Cancel reply",'domain');
$link = esc_html( remove_query_arg('replytocom') ) . '#respond';
$style = isset($_GET['replytocom']) ? '' : ' style="display:none;"';
$formatted_link = '<p class="cancel-comment-reply pull-right" '.$style.'><a title="'.$cancel_text.'" href="'.$link.'">'. $cancel_text . '</a></p>';

$args = array(
  'cancel_reply_link' => cancel_comment_reply_link(apply_filters( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', $formatted_link, $link, $cancel_text )),
// other args and usual comment template as in wordpress codex
);
comment_form($args);
```

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 2):

The link markup passes through the filter named, guess what, [`cancel_comment_reply_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/cancel_comment_reply_link/).

Something along the lines of (not tested):

```
add_filter( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', function( $formatted_link ) {

    return 'before' . $formatted_link . 'after';
} );
```

It will still get wrapped into `<small>` in `comment_form()` later though, which might or might not be relevant and unfortunately seems hard to get rid of.

Comment: I hear you @Rarst, I updated the question, maybe somebody somehow... Thanks

Comment: I am not following what you mean by "3 links", please always include relevant code you had tried into your question.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Ehm, that's not quite a way to use a filter. :) I would recommend to read up on `add_filter()` and stuff.

Comment: Please, I've spent half a year coding some JS, I'm a bit left behind with my PHP skill and Wordpress research, can you please share a sample code that would do? Thank you so much.